# How to authorize in Skype web SDK

Tags: javascript, skype

Recently preview version of new Skype SDK has been released. So I've downloaded samples, read MSDN articles and tried to write simplest JS script to make login to this SDK. So, I've taken code from this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn962162(v=office.16).aspx) and slightly modified it(sample code hasn't been working at all - used wrong variable). Modified code works, but returns error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null at https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:8982:77 at handle (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:2220:63) at https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:698:34".
```

So my code is below:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';    // create an instance of the Application object;
    // note, that different instances of Application may
    // represent different users
    var Application
    var client;
    Skype.initialize({
        apiKey: 'SWX-BUILD-SDK',
    }, function (api) {
        Application = api.application;
        client = new Application();


        // when the user clicks on the "Sign In" button    $('#signin').click(function () {
        // start signing in
        client.signInManager.signIn({
            username: 'login',
            password: 'pass'
        }).then(
            //onSuccess callback
            function () {
                // when the sign in operation succeeds display the user name
                alert('Signed in as ' + application.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
            },
            //onFailure callback
            function (error) {
                // if something goes wrong in either of the steps above,
                // display the error message
                alert(error || 'Cannot sign in');
            });
    }, function (err) {
        alert('some error occurred: ' + err);
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found right answer: [for now Skype Web SDK is only for Skype for Business not Skype for consumers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2456ef60-b37f-44d7-b1ef-4cb46b89fc6a/regular-skype?forum=SkypeWebSDK). Sad but true.